# How to create csv file and share it without save to local storage in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm fresh in flutter and try to make a simple app that do the following:

1. take some text
2. create csv file
3. share it to another device.

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472270/how-to-create-and-export-csv-file-in-flutter)

I success with first and third part, but stuck in the second:
I don't want to handle any permission, so I don't want to store the file in local storage.

in the next step, my app should work both android and iOS.

Thanks

I already try to use "to_csv" package, but get Gradle error.

Comment: The solution to your query can be located at the following link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472270/how-to-create-and-export-csv-file-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472270/how-to-create-and-export-csv-file-in-flutter).

Comment: That exactly the link I mention in the question.
But I figure it possible to store in cache dir and there is no permission handling.. so my question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it possible to store in cache Directory, so there is no need to handle permissions:

```
    import 'dart:io' show Directory, File;
    import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
    import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'
.
.
.

  void _onPressed() async {
        List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert('a,b,c');
        String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rowsAsListOfValues);
        final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        String filePath = "${tempDir.path}/list.csv";
        print(filePath);
        File file = File(filePath);
        await file.writeAsString(csv);
        final result = await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(filePath)], text: '');
        if (result.status == ShareResultStatus.success) {
          print('Thank you for sharing!');
        }
}
```